I need to configure a USB with grub bootloader+kernel that will be used on a different PC. How to do it without without affecting the running linux?
I've searched and I found answers that are applicable to my scenario in part, but in trying I can see that I'm still missing or not understanding some critical aspects. I have a running linux(debian) which is my operational platform and works fine.  What I am working on is to create a USB that I will be seen by another PC.  This USB needs to be bootable with GRUB and it will contain its own version of Linux kernel. Most of the answers I found basically would use my operational Linux with its running GRUB to install to the USB MBR, but the rest of the update/config also affects my running Linux rather than just the USB.  For instance, I need to create a specific menu that must be used only by the GRUB on the USB and not on my Linux. In simple words if my Linux has GRub (A) as its bootloader, can I do an independent GRub (B) setup but point it to only install on the USB and that it never touches any files relative to GRub (A)?  GRub refers to /etc but that is only on a running system. How could I keep a separate set of secondary /etc that is the base for the USB installation? There are options that I can use on grub-install, but it still seems to assume just one running GRub. There is one post that assumes one is running from an iso image, but that's not my case.

The Grub2 menu is simply a text file, easily edited in Kate, gedit or otherwise: https://www.howtogeek.com/196655/how-to-configure-the-grub2-boot-loaders-settings/. Just edit the menu on the USB.
